# AngularFire-seed: What happens with function argument

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In the [AngularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) this happens in the [run-definition](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/app.js):

```
$rootScope.auth = loginService.init('/login');
```

Then in [loginService-definition](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/service.login.js):

```
init: function() {
  return auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef());
},
```

And [firebaseRef](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/service.firebase.js) is a service that looks like this:

```
return function(path) {
  return new Firebase(pathRef([FBURL].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))));
}
```

The [FBURL](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/config.js) is a constant:

```
.constant('FBURL', 'https://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com')
```

So for me it looks like the '/login' is the part of the path in the firebase-reference. But if so, should it not be passed on like this?

```
init: function(path) {
  return auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef(path));
},
```

So the question is really: What happens with the "/login" argument on the top? For me it looks like it is "lost" in the init-function. But since this is made by the Firebase-people, I am sure there is a meaning behind it and there is something that I do not understand here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/login` argument is an artifact from an older version of [RouteSecurity](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/module.routeSecurity.js) and is no longer used.

It was replaced by `loginRedirectPath` in [config.js](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/config.js#L11).

The `path` has no bearing on authentication in Firebase as you authenticate against the entire instance no matter what child paths you might pass in the reference to $firebaseSimpleLogin.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, Kato! I am not blind after all :)